# Удалить повреждённую папку

Tags: windows

При попытке удалить папку появляется сообщение о том что "Невозможно удалить папку так как она повреждена". Пробовал удалить через Unlocker - не помогает. Что делать(желательно без форматирования всего диска)?

Comment: Выполнить полную проверку диска?

Comment: Как это сделать(я просто новичок в подобных вещах)?

Comment: В окне свойств нужного диска, там вкладочка «Сервис» есть

Comment: ````chkdsk````?

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать через консоль, с помощью команды rd/path . Где path - путь к папке.